# text scrolling in tranparent header html css

Tags: html, css

I'm using a transparent header for my website with a scrollable background. But i want to make the content disappear below the header. please find my code here http://jsfiddle.net/prta/yw0w4d3p/1/ . Any help is appreciated.

CSS

```
body {
    color:white;
}
header {
    position:fixed;
}
li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 20px 0 20px;
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:red;
    font-size:50px;
}
.bg {
    width:100%;
    height:100% auto;
    background: url(http://southerngaragebands.com/Aero_Woods.jpg); 
    margin-top: -20px;

}
p {
    margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;
    font-size:30px;
    padding-top:100px;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: As an aside- note that `id` attributes starting with a number are invalid...they should start with aZ

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. Do you want the image to show behind the header, but not the text?

Comment: Yeah, the background must be seen behind the header during scroll. but the text must disappear below the header.

Answer (score 0):

Set background color for header. you can set width as you want and you decrease opacity if you want     (opacity:0.8).

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: I think this is not what the OP wants

Comment: yeah.. this not what i'm look for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this works exactly the way you want but this is one of the option that i found you can put your text in a div and give it `position:fixed` and then give it `overflow:scroll;` that way you can maintain the position of your header but this doesn't work if the page is scrolled http://jsfiddle.net/yw0w4d3p/9/

```
#a{
margin-top:100px;
position:fixed;
overflow:scroll;
height:100%;
width:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example, it may help you out! 
You can use `position:absolute` and `overflow:auto` to get the result.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8SUmn/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can use fixed background it's not a big deal, but if u want it to be scrollable background then I don't think u can make it work without some kind of a javascript here and since all the answers use `fixed` `background-attachment`, here is my shot. Header is not `transparent` but uses same background as the `.bg` block

http://jsfiddle.net/yw0w4d3p/18/

```css
body {
    color:white;
        margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
    position:fixed;
       background: url("http://southerngaragebands.com/Aero_Woods.jpg") repeat fixed 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
       width: 100%;
}
li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 20px 0 20px;
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:red;
    font-size:50px;
}
.bg {
     background: url("http://southerngaragebands.com/Aero_Woods.jpg") repeat fixed 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
     margin-top: -20px;
     width: 100%;
   
}
p {
    margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;
    font-size:30px;
    padding-top:100px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#one">one</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#two">two</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#three">three</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
<div id="one" class="bg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce placerat sapien eget ligula egestas, quis aliquam velit varius. Phasellus mollis mollis sem quis porttitor. Pellentesque scelerisque mauris et magna tincidunt, vel pharetra enim pharetra. Duis a lobortis purus. Sed dignissim fermentum nibh convallis eleifend. In quis interdum arcu. Proin interdum, lorem et luctus laoreet, felis purus pharetra turpis, eu egestas justo ligula in lectus. Morbi vitae libero vel velit posuere luctus at eu diam. Duis tincidunt lectus ut lobortis euismod. Vivamus ultrices tristique sapien eget posuere.</p>
</div>
<div id="two" class="bg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce placerat sapien eget ligula egestas, quis aliquam velit varius. Phasellus mollis mollis sem quis porttitor. Pellentesque scelerisque mauris et magna tincidunt, vel pharetra enim pharetra. Duis a lobortis purus. Sed dignissim fermentum nibh convallis eleifend. In quis interdum arcu. Proin interdum, lorem et luctus laoreet, felis purus pharetra turpis, eu egestas justo ligula in lectus. Morbi vitae libero vel velit posuere luctus at eu diam. Duis tincidunt lectus ut lobortis euismod. Vivamus ultrices tristique sapien eget posuere.</p>
</div>
<div id="three" class="bg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce placerat sapien eget ligula egestas, quis aliquam velit varius. Phasellus mollis mollis sem quis porttitor. Pellentesque scelerisque mauris et magna tincidunt, vel pharetra enim pharetra. Duis a lobortis purus. Sed dignissim fermentum nibh convallis eleifend. In quis interdum arcu. Proin interdum, lorem et luctus laoreet, felis purus pharetra turpis, eu egestas justo ligula in lectus. Morbi vitae libero vel velit posuere luctus at eu diam. Duis tincidunt lectus ut lobortis euismod. Vivamus ultrices tristique sapien eget posuere.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to achieve the effect using JS?